# Como instruir o eslint a resolver caminhos absolutos com babel-plugin-root-import em monorepos

Tags: javascript, react, babel, eslint

Possuo um repositório *monorepo* feito com *yarn* e neste tenho um projeto *frontend* criado com o comando `create-react-app`. Instalei as *libs* **react-app-rewired** e **customize-cra** para injetar as configurações ao babel do plugin **babel-plugin-root-import** e estas estão funcionado corretamente,  meu projeto é executado sem erros, segue código do meu arquivo config-overrides.js

```
const { addBabelPlugin, override } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugin([
    'babel-plugin-root-import',
    {
      rootPathSuffix: 'src',
    },
  ])
);
```

O problema ocorre com o meu *eslint* que não reconhece os caminhos dos meus arquivos. Instalei a *lib* **eslint-import-resolver-babel-plugin-root-import** para lidar com situação, e acrescentei ao meu arquivo .eslintrc.json a seguinte configuração

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "babel-plugin-root-import": {
      "rootPathSuffix": "src"
    }
  }
}
```

Apesar das instruções no arquivo de configuração do *eslint* estarem de acordo com as instruções na [documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-babel-plugin-root-import), o *eslint* continua a não reconhecer os caminhos de arquios como válidos. estou importado meus arquivos da seguinte forma

```
import SignIn from '~/pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from '~/pages/SignUp';
import Dashboard from '~/pages/Dashboard';
import Profile from '~/pages/Profile';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorre por conta da estrutura de *monorepo* do projeto. Nas configurações do arquivo *eslint* o parâmetro de **rootPathSuffix** do **babel-plugin-root-import** parte da raiz do projeto e NÃO do diretório onde o arquivo *eslint* se encontra. Para ficar mais claro, a estrutura abaixo representa um modelo *monorepo* do *yarn*.

```
frontend
- src
- package.json
- .eslintrc.json
mobile
- src
- package.json
- .eslintrc.json
package.json
.editorconfig
```

Os projetos de *frontend* e *mobile* possuem configurações diferentes do eslint, para configurar o **babel-plugin-root-import** para o projeto de *mobile* por exemplo, a seguinte configuração é necessária:

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "babel-plugin-root-import": {
      "rootPathSuffix": "mobile/src"
    }
  }
}
```

Em qualquer estrutura de pastas do seu projeto, adicione o valor do parâmetro **rootPathSuffix** de modo que todo o caminho do projeto, indo de sua raiz até o diretório desejado, seja contemplado no valor.